# Rendering show in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am getting along really well with customizing active admin, but I can't get this to work:

In app/admin/orders.rb I have

```
show do
  render "show"
end
```

In app/views/admin/orders/_show.html.erb I simply have

```
<h3>Test</h3>
<% panel "General" do %>
<% end %>
```

Now the h3 Test is rendered just fine but the empty panel "General" gets rendered on top of the page!

So I get

```
<div class="panel">
  <h3>General</h3>
  <div class="panel_contents"></div>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
...
```

Very strange...

Thanks, I would really appreciate some help on this one!

Comment: I am having the same problem! Did anyone manage to solve this?

Comment: Hi, no I didn't find a solution at that time. Now I'm on a different project, so I did not try any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[The ActiveAdmin's docs mention render in `show` blocks](http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-screens.html) and apparently it is supposed to work. Maybe you should file an issue in the project's GitHub page?

EDIT: Hey, maybe the issue stems from the name of the partial. Have you tried naming the partial differently, ie. not "show"?

And btw, have you tried using `capture`? Maybe it could help. Haven't tested it, though.

```
show do
  capture do
    render 'show'
  end
end
```